# "save the changes" message after removing the protection from workbook Excel 2010

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, passwords

Some time ago I protected the Excel 2010 file from the path *File > Protect workbook > Encrypt with password* and gave it a password. Now that I removed that password via below method:

*Open the workbook and use Save As
In the lower right of the file window will be "Tools"
Choose "General Options"
Clear the password.
Save over your old file.*

the file is openable without wanting a password. But the problem is when I open it and close it immediately, even without moving the active cell, the message "*Do you want to save the changes you made to 'test.lsx'?*" appears. While there hasn't occurred any changes to that file so why I face this message any time I want to close the file? 
Hasn't the file been corrupted?

Comment: Yes, the problem was about the _=TODAY()_ function. BUT, does this function should have this behavior on any .xlsx files always?

Answer (score 0):

If you have double clicked on any cell(s) or have  selected the cell or added the cursor on Formula Bar  then it would ask you for saving changes irrespective of whether any change has been made or not.

Comment: assume I open the file and then close it immediately. I only move the mouse to the X mark or the upper-right corner and close the file. I even don't move the mouse to the area of the sheet or the buttons. In this situation the message appear again.